# Is it possible to sort the user result returned by facebook search request according to mutual friends

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-fql

I am trying to use facebook search https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=vartika&type=user&access_token=

the result are same for all the users.
I want the result specific to particular user,returning the user list sorted by number of  mutual friends  if any and then random users.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible to sort the user result returned by facebook search request according to mutual friends

**NO**,

but I think facebook gives different results to different users, provided access_token is different. Can you check again ?

and yes, you can get specific results based on locality

```
https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=harsh&type=user&center=37.76,-122.427&distance=1000&access_token=<access_token>
```

Reference:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/#searching

Comment: Yes i tried with different access_tokens results were the same.

Comment: I mean access_token from different users (not the different access token for same user)

When I search for `harsh` , first result is of my friend harsh vardhan gupta. And I am damn sure, you wont get that harsh as first result :). In any case,I've given the answer. If that doesnt help you, facebook doesnt give results based on mutual friends. You can try based on locality instead. Mark as answer if it helps you :)

Comment: can you please mention the search query , will try at my end

Comment: To make the question clear again

We want to search people by their company/ institute

How to the same results as facebook gives in a search on their site?

 

When Anant searches for goldman sachs and hit the magnifying glass on fb site, and click on people on the search filters on the left:

 

URL in browser - http://www.facebook.com/search/results.php?q=goldman%20sachs&type=users&init=quick&tas=0.7287932067171547

 

Results

 

Atul Anand [friend]

Uttam Garg [friend]

Goldmann Sachs 

David Sachs

Aaron Goldman

Nitin Jain 

Rupesh Kumar

 Continued .....

Comment: When searched via graph API, I get results.         

https://graph.facebook.com/search?q=goldman%20sachs&type=user&access_token=<anant's access token>

 

Archana Jain

MJ Walton

Sheryl WuDunn

Seda Y\u0131ld\u0131z

Waithaka David

 

Why can't we get the same results?

 

Also - we would like to search on the company field, instead of searching in "all fields". Like Goldman Sachs" returns people with Goldman in their names.

Comment: I tried using different access token from different users but still result was same. Can you please let me know the query